# How to move to start of current command in zsh

Tags: zsh

I'm using vi mode with zsh, but I'm stuck in moving to start of current command when there are multiple lines in it.

With `0`, it just moves to the start of current line rather than current command.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

It's `gg` in command mode like in `vim` to move to the start of the editing buffer:

```
$ bindkey -M vicmd | grep begi
"^[[1~" vi-beginning-of-line
"0" vi-digit-or-beginning-of-line
"gg" beginning-of-buffer-or-history
```

(that `^[[1~`, the escape sequence sent upon <kbd>Home</kbd> in my terminal emulator was added by my distribution config file, the two other ones are standard in `zsh`).